# Using DependsOn with Fn::ImportValue in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to use DependsOn with Fn::ImportValue like this?

```
"DependsOn": {"Fn::ImportValue": {
            "Fn::Sub": "${MyStack1}-VPCGatewayAttachment"
        }}
```

To be specific, I have my VPC and InternetGatewayAttchment in one stack. I'm import this stack in Stack2 where I have my ELB and I'm trying to use DependsOn to depend on this attachment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand a bit on your specific case, if you think you need to add the [`DependsOn`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) attribute to the [`AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc-gateway-attachment.html) because of the documentation's recommendation [When a DependsOn attribute is required](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html#gatewayattachment), note that these recommendations only apply for resources defined **in the same template**:

> If your AWS CloudFormation template defines a VPC, a gateway, and a gateway attachment, any resources that require the gateway are dependent on the gateway attachment.

When the gateway attachment is defined in a separate template, you don't need to explicitly declare any additional dependency. As long as the application stack gets deleted before the network stack, the dependent resource will get deleted before the VPC-gateway attachment.

In general, as mentioned in [George M Whitaker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41120779/2518355), declaring a `DependsOn` between stacks is never necessary. Since you can't delete a stack if another stack references one of its outputs, using `Fn::ImportValue` to create a cross-stack reference creates a dependency that the stack containing the reference must be deleted before the stack being referenced.

Answer (score 8):

You should not use [DependsOn](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) like this. It is only needed when creating dependencies between resources within a template. Specifically it is used to override the sequence Cloudformation creates resources.

The `FN::ImportValue` is inherently a dependent function since the Exported Value must exist before stack generation. So just reference your Import Value in the appropriate resource.